# Wheres the best place Iphone app to place a Data Model instance and how would you Access it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, uiviewcontroller

I am learning tons on this thing. Reading also, but this is awesome!

Ok.. so long story sort I hope. I'm making a data class to pump out some instances of people that have various attributes. I would like my view controllers to be able to access them (through properties of course.. I think) to manipulate their data.

Where in an iphone app would be the best place to do this, and how would you write the code to message to this object. My current setup would be to have a navigation controller with a firstlevelviewcontroller that created a few secondlevelviewcontroller children instances that would do things like pickers for date of birth, and height, weight, etc.

Could the Navigation Controller make these model objects? Should application delegate? Lets say application delegate does. If so, then how would I put references to these objects from my first and second level view controllers?

Awesome!

**Update for the new millenium. **

I'm reading on core data structures, and though they are awesome, they are above and beyond what I need for this project. what I need is simple, I think..

I want one class that is a data class with a few variables that I can manipulate. I want to manipulate these from two view controllers. I might want more than one data instance, so I don't want a singleton data object. I don't need a persistent store of data.

I would like to know how to step by step have this data class instantiated.. should it be in app delegate? can i do it somewhere else? I dont want it a child of one of the view controllers.. How would I do that? then, how would I reference it from the view controllers and manipulate data (I'm pretty sure through properties but I can't figure out how to reference the instances to make this happen).

CHeers! thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Lots of questions that fringe on conjunction of various best practices.

First, the NSManagedObjectContext (if instantiated in the application delegate) can be shared in any number of ways. You can push it on through as you load your controllers or, something I've been more want to do (and will gladly argue the merits), you can hand it off to a Singleton that any controller has access to.

Depending on the model graph and how your UI maps to the data objects (you didn't say), keep in mind being memory friendly. I defer creating the NSFetchRequests until there is a controller that needs the data (CRUD).

If you want to edit your question or add comments that may provide more clarity... the answer may change

Frank